# EditView perform an action on click

Tags: java, android, xml, editview

I have an `EditView` and I have added :

```
android:imeActionLabel="Go"
```

This is showing "Go" button in keyboard, but I don't know how to perform an action when user clicks "Go" button.

Is there any solution about this, if yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EditText.OnEditorActionListener` is what you are looking for, the API Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html). The action that will be called for the GO button is `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO`. I have provided a brief example below.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
{
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)
            {
                    //Handle go button pressed
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: It is showing this error at `OnEditorActionListener()`: The type new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method TextView.OnEditorActionListener.onEditorAction(TextView, int, KeyEvent)

Comment: Yes, you must implement the method that I have above (onEditorAction), the Overridden one. If you copy the code above and change "editText" to the name of your EditText it will work as expected. Or you can let the class you are writing in implement OnEditorActionListener if you have more than one and they are static.

Comment: I have added all the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/s8n8s/ . Please just check what I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s8n8s/2/ Fixed your issues. If it still doesn't work the issue is unrelated to the creation of the onEditorActionListener

Comment: It is not showing any error but it is also not adding the green color. I have added EditText here: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/s8n8s/3/

Comment: Put a log in the onEditorAction call to make sure it is getting called and that IME_ACTION_GO is being triggered as the actionId, anything past that is out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: Ok I added a toast and it worked good. Maybe the `if` statement is not working.

Comment: Move the toast to inside the if statement then, I'm sorry but as I said this discussion is getting far too specific and outside the scope of your original question, there's not much more I can do to help you that cannot be gleamed from a few minutes of playing around with android.

Comment: Actually I just went through your JSFiddle xml code again and found the issue, you are changing the label not the imeOptions, so in order to isolate it as an actual go button (with standard functionality you should change the imeOption in the EditText xml file. Or you can leave it as it is and not use the IME check

Comment: So I am new in android, I don't know so much please can you give me the code I need to add. I tried android:imeOptions="Go", but it is showing an error in "Go"